# No MVVM Light templates or snippets with NuGet v4.1.21 install

Tags: mvvm-light

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1

I had previously installed MVVM Light using the v4.0.0.19 MSI installer and really like it.  With the release of v4.1.21 I decided to switch to NuGet, so I uninstalled the old version and installed the newer (full) version using NuGet.  I no longer have MVVM Light templates or snippets.

Any help getting the templates and snippets would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get an answer? I've run into this issue today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget will only add the references to MVVMLight in your project; it won't make any changes to your Visual Studio installation.

Comment: Thanks, rod, I wasn't aware of that.  So now my question becomes "How do I get the snippets and templates without an MSI?"